# Export Yii Models with Relations into diagram

Tags: php, activerecord, frameworks, yii, models

we have to create a schema diagramm of all AR Models in our Yii Project and before I start doing this manually i wanted to ask you if there maybe exists any extension out there. I appreciate any answer which could help saving some hours.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: what kind of database? MySQL?

Comment: and are these relations represented as external keys in the dataqbase?

Comment: yes we use mysql but without foreign keys ... all the relations are defined in the models

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If You define foreign keys between tables matching the relations between models [MySQL Workbench](http://www.mysql.com/products/workbench/) can generate a schema diagram from the current schema, hope it helps

To do this, got to Database > Reverse Engineering